# R - select last 2 columns

Tags: r, select

I have an dataframe below, in reality it actually has much more columns, and I´d like to select only last two columns.

```
   df <- read.table(text="
                 date1       date2              date3
    1            NA          2016-12-01    2016-12-01
    2            2017-01-01  2018-10-01    2016-12-01 
    3            2016-12-01  NA            2016-12-01
    4            NA          NA            2016-12-01
", header=TRUE)
```

How can I do it without specifying column names?

```
df %>%
  select(date2, date3)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `select` with `tail` to get last 2 column names

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% select(tail(names(.), 2))

#       date2      date3
#1 2016-12-01 2016-12-01
#2 2018-10-01 2016-12-01
#3       <NA> 2016-12-01
#4       <NA> 2016-12-01
```

which in base R is

```
df[tail(names(df), 2)]
```

Comment: Nice. The concept works without `dplyr` too: `df[,tail(names(df),2)]`

Comment: @EdwardCarney yes, you are right. I have included that as well in the answer.

Comment: Thats perferct, how you select togheder first and last columns?

Comment: @Sklenicka you mean `df %>% select(1, tail(names(.), 2))` ?

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party. Just for the records, there's a convenient way in `tidyverse` to select the last column(s):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  select(last_col(offset = 1), last_col())

       date2      date3
1 2016-12-01 2016-12-01
2 2018-10-01 2016-12-01
3       <NA> 2016-12-01
4       <NA> 2016-12-01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[Source](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/everything.html)

Selecting the first column(s) is straight forward:

```r
> df %>% 
+   select(1,2)
       date1      date2
1       <NA> 2016-12-01
2 2017-01-01 2018-10-01
3 2016-12-01       <NA>
4       <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

We can just make use of `ncol`

```
df[(ncol(df)-1):ncol(df)]
#       date2      date3
#1 2016-12-01 2016-12-01
#2 2018-10-01 2016-12-01
#3       <NA> 2016-12-01
#4       <NA> 2016-12-01
```

---

Or using `select_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    select_at((ncol(.)-1) : ncol(.))
```

Comment: Or slightly modifying the first suggestion: `df[-(1:(ncol(df)-n))]`, where using `n` you can just specify how many columns you want from the end. In the case of the example dataframe, it would be `df[-(1:(ncol(df)-2))]`

Answer (score 0):

Without dplyr:

```
df.minus.2.columns <- df[,c(-1,-2)]
```

Sorry, no idea how you'd do so with dplyr.

Comment: The minus indexing means dropping columns. This answer drops the first and second columns leaving only the third left (returned as a list).

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr and using vectorized operations, you can select the last `n` observations with:

```
n <- 2
library(tidyverse)
df %>% tail()
df %>% select(last_col()-(n-1):0) %>% tail()

       date2      date3
1 2016-12-01 2016-12-01
2 2018-10-01 2016-12-01
3       <NA> 2016-12-01
4       <NA> 2016-12-01
```